# genealogytree sandclock

Tags: genealogytree

I am making a sandclock construction with the genealogytree software (see picture and code below). Is there a way to add the families of aunt or uncle? The second picture is what I would like to get.

[image: sandclock with proband=g0]

```
\genealogytree[template=signpost]
 {sandclock
  {parent{c[female]{sister in law}
       p[male]{father in law}p[female]{mother in law}  
       g[female]{wife} 
    } 
    parent[id=fam0]
    { g[id=g0,male]{g0} 
       parent{p[female]{grandmother}
              p[male]{grandfather}c[male]{uncle}
              g[id=p0,female]{mother} 
              } 
       parent{p[male]{grandfather} 
              p[female]{grandmother}
              g[male]{father} c[female]{aunt}
             } 
       c[id=c2,male]{brother} c[female]{sister}
     } 
      child[id=famp1]{p[male]{son in law}
                      c[female]{granddaughter}
                      g[id=p1,female]{daughter}
                      }   
      child{p[female]{daughter in law}
            g[id=gp1,male]{son}
            c[male]{grandson}
            } 
  }
 }
```

[image: desired result]

Comment: it would be helpful if you could provide a handrawn sketch to show what is the desired output

Comment: I have edited the post to add a picture showing aunt's husband and aunt's son. I have manually added that with tikz but I would like to know if genealogytree could do it.

Comment: is there something else you look for -- you have not accepted the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

The creation of the `aunt` tree has been created above where `A` represent the `aunt husband` -- this has been done by opening a new tree and creating an `aunt` node at the very same coordinates -- think of it as a `phantom aunt` conveniently called `haunt` -- now we can hook into this `phantom` node and create any family tree on the `aunt` side -- i have only created the A node representing the husband of aunt  -- i think you will be able to procreate further

### The code for phantom aunt

```
\genealogytree[set position=phantomaunt at aunt]{
      child{
            g[male,id=phantomaunt]{aunt}
            p{A}
      }}
```

[image]

### The MWE

Added some prettifying

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all]{genealogytree}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\genealogytree[template=signpost]{
 sandclock{
    parent{
          c[female]{sister in law}%
          p[male]{father in law}
          p[female]{mother in law}  
          g[female]{wife}} 
          parent[id=fam0]{
                          g[id=g0,male]{g0} 
                    parent{
                          p[female]{grandmother}
                          p[male]{grandfather}
                          c[male]{uncle}
                          g[id=p0,female]{mother}} 
          parent{
                p[male]{grandfather} 
                 p[female]{grandmother}
                 g[male]{father} 
                 c[female, id=aunt]{aunt}} 
                 c[id=c2,male]{brother} 
                 c[female]{sister}} 
          child[id=famp1]{%
                 p[male]{son in law}
                 c[female]{granddaughter}
                 g[id=p1,female]{daughter}}   
          child{
                p[female]{daughter in law}
                g[id=gp1,male]{son}
                c[male]{grandson}}}}
\genealogytree[set position=phantomaunt at aunt, options for family={auntA}
                                                {extra edges prepend={phantomaunt}{A}{
                                                foreground={red!25!yellow,line width=5pt}}}]{
  child[id=auntA, family box={colback=green!50}]{
        g[male,id=phantomaunt]{aunt}
        p[male, id=A]{A}
  }}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, this solves my problem. From your solution, I assume that it is impossible to include an aunt's husband on a single sandclock construction. One has to make a second tree and connect it to the first, right? I am also assuming the same will be true if I wanted to add a husband for sister in law.

Comment: it can be done but thats an answer for another day

Comment: @js-bibra Can you give us any hints how to realize this without restructuring the entire tree from `parent` to `child`?

Comment: @MrD it is an old answer -- please let me know exactly what is the problem in detail